# Stream data from Rest via GET

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I have a client application that connect to an external REST server in order to read some data.
My application sends a request to REST server: http://myCompany.com/v1/streamingdata
and then it gets responses (if any), for example:

- Now: "Abc"
- 5 seconds later: "Efg"
- 3 seconds later: "Hij"
- 30 seconds later: heartbeat
- 8 seconds later: "Klm"
- ....

I do that in python in following way:

```
response = get("http://myCompany.com/v1/streamingdata".format(first_stream['id']), stream=True)
it = response.iter_lines(chunk_size=1)
for chunk in it:
  print(json.loads(chunk))

def get(path, stream=False):
  uri_with_jwt = generate_url(endpoint, path, "GET")
  return requests.get(uri_with_jwt, "GET", stream=stream)
```

How do I achieve that in .NET ?
I can connect, I am able to get single responses, but I can't get it listening for the responses:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri("http://myCompany.com/v1/streamingdata"),
    Headers =
    {
        { "Accept-Encoding", "identity" }
    }
})
{
    await GetStream(session, request);
}

public static async Task GetStream(HttpClient session, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var response = HandleResponse(
        await session.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
);

var content = response.Content;
```

Any advices?

Comment: What do you actually want to *do* with the stream? Note that a long-running HTTP response is generally a bad idea unless using WebSockets. gRPC or SignalR might be a better idea.

Comment: Use SSE or WebSockets for long-life'd response streams - returning a `Stream` from a Controller Action is intended for finite-length things, like binary files. And it's redundant to generate/send/verify heartbeats yourself: that's built-in to SSE and WebSockets.

Comment: My comment above assumes you're asking how to write a streaming response generator on the server, not the client. On the client-side (with `HttpClient`) you should take a look at [.NET Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines) which is intended for parsing messages out of streams (especially async streams where the messages aren't aligned with stream buffer boundaries).

Comment: To get results in a stream the *only* thing you need is `var stream=await client.GetStreamAsync(url);`. It seems like the actual question is how to retrieve "streaming JSON" (quotes intentional). Since you already have the response stream, you can read one line at a time and parse it. This process is *very* fragile though, because HTTP simply doesn't support multiple responses. There's only a single response that's kept open for a long time and can get terminated for any number of reasons, by the client, server or proxies. Long running responses seriously harm server scalability too

Comment: If you want streaming responses, use a protocol that actually supports them like gRPC or WebSockets.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I will stick to httpClient for now, since this is just for prototype.
Unfortunately I can get 'var stream=await client.GetStreamAsync(url);' working, it simply waits on that line, nothing happens despite messages  being sent by a client.